# ScriptEngineManager: How to make a http request from JavaScript Engine

Tags: javascript, java, scriptengine

I'm, using `javax.script.ScriptEngineManager`, in which, im using the JS Script Engine, like this.

```
ScriptEngineManager manager = new ScriptEngineManager();
ScriptEngine engine = manager.getEngineByName("js");
engine.eval(str);//str contains JS code as String
Invocable inv = (Invocable) engine;
Object[] objAry = {"Sample String input"};//input ary
Object objOutput = inv.invokeFunction(fuctionName, objAry);//function name & input ary
```

Now, I want to execute, JS code which will make a HTTP request.
Currently, I'm trying with this script.

```
function httpGet(theUrl)
{
    var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlHttp.open( "GET", theUrl, false );
    xmlHttp.send( null );
    return xmlHttp.responseText;
}
```

But, it is not supported, as I guess, this code, is for browser.

**Therefore, My question is, How to make a HTTP call from JS code, which is executing via javax.script.ScriptEngineManager?**

And, currently, I'm using jdk7.

Comment: i didn't find a working solution but you can check rhino project by mozila. you can call java code with js